# loop through data frame to plot all possible cases

Tags: r, plot, dataframe

I have a data set (mydata), which a part of this is like the following:

```
'data.frame':  36190 obs. of 16 variables: 

$ RE                    : int  38 41 11 67 30 18 38 41 41 30 ... 

$ LU                    : int  4200 3330 530 4500 3000 1790 4700 3400   

$ COUNTRY               : Factor w/ 4 levels "DE","FR","JP", "FR"… 

$Light                  : Factor w/2 levels  "ON","OFF","ON", …. 

$OR                     : Factor w/2 levels  "S","T","S",…. 

$PAT                    : Factor w/3 levels  "low", "high", "middle",….
```

now I want to plot RE vs LU for all the possible cases, for example one plot for (COUNTRY= FR, Light=off, OR=S, PAT=low) and one for (COUNTRY= FR, Light=on, OR=S, PAT=high) one for (COUNTRY= FR, Light=off, OR=S, PAT=high)and so on. I have created a data frame like following but I don't know how to loop over this data frame and generate all the plots using ggplot2

```
mydata <- data.frame( RE = sample( 5:50, 100, TRUE), LU = sample(1500:4500, 100 ), COUNTRY = factor( sample( c( "DE","FR","JP","AU"), 100, TRUE)),Light=factor( sample( c( "ON", "OFF" ), 100, TRUE)), OR = factor( sample( c( "S", "T" ), 100, TRUE)), PAT = factor( sample( c( "low", "high", "middle" ),100,TRUE)))
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: do you really want 4*2*2*3 = 48 plots?

Comment: Try using facets instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
ggplot(data=mydata,aes(x=LU,y=RE))+geom_point()+facet_grid(COUNTRY+LIGHT~OR+PAT)
```

you can change the variable inside facet_grid(COUNTRY+LIGHT~OR+PAT) to control columns/rows divisions.

this plot was made with 1000 samples to give some data-volume

[image]